# Windows Mobile 6 Version Compatibility

Tags: windows-mobile

Does a CAB file that was developed with the Windows Mobile 6 SDK deploy and run on Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications written for WinMo 6.0 will run on 6.1 (and 6.5).

As for the CAB file itself, it depends on what information was given in [the INF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924764.aspx) used when generating it.  The [CEDevice section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms938382.aspx) has VersionMin and VersionMax fields that could be used to narrow the deployment scope to just WinMo 6.0 if desired.

The default version settings in a Smart Device CAB project in Studio, however, is broad enough to allow both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In fact if you don't use any new WM6 API's, it will also install and run on WM5.